# Center element between another element and left side of screen (html/css)

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div between the left side of the screen and a right floated div. I want to achieve exactly what `margin:auto;` usually does, unfortunately `margin:auto;` does not work when floated elements are involved somehow.

left element (that should be centered):

```
.wcard{
  float: left;
  /* margin:auto; */
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: separate;
  padding: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #b2b2b2;
}
```

right element:

```
.slidein ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 4px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}
```

html:

```
   <body>
    <header>
        <img id = "menu" src="static/images/menunav.png">
    </header>
    <div class="wcard">
    </div>
    <div class="slidein">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Techniques</li>
            <li>About me</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Visual representation of what i want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: JSFiddle with html please

Comment: Or at least a *question* with the HTML please

Comment: the html is extremely trivial but ill include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's **exactly** what you want to achieve 
the idea of creating a big container then divide it into two ones and then `margin:auto` the div inside the one you need

```css
  html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: tomato;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 70px)
  }
  .left{
    float: left;
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .right{
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .centered {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<header></header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
    <div class="centered"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you are trying to achieve. I started answering your question before you posted the html code so I created everything from scratch. I would advice you to use Bootstrap so you can mage your web page a bit more responsive.

This is for the floating left image:

```
#left{
  width:50%;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-top:10%;
}
```

The entire thing can be seen in this JS Fiddle: [Solution #1](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26293/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works great if the left div is static, but the thing is as the right div slides in from the right (its going to be a slide in menu) the left div needs to adjust its horizontal position. That's why i need something like `margin: auto;` but between the left side of the screen and a right floated element.

Comment: Sorry if you answer didn't help, I find your explanation a bit confusing.

Comment: @Bonbin you may see my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wcard{
  /* margin:auto; */
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: separate;
  padding: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #b2b2b2;
  margin: auto;
}


.slidein ul {
  padding: 4px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}


main {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <img id = "menu" src="static/images/menunav.png">
    </header>
  
    <main>
      <div class="wcard">
        this should be centered
      </div>
    </main>
  
    <nav class="slidein">
      <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Projects</li>
          <li>Techniques</li>
          <li>About me</li>
          <li></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to "center" `.wcard` add:

```
margin-top: calc(25vh - 40px);
margin-left: calc(50vw - 70px);
```

If it's not in the position you want you can easily position `.wcard` by adjusting the margins. Note that vw and vh are used to make it responsive. Details are commented in Snippet

#### SNIPPET

```css
/* This is just for help us visualize where each element is */

* {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
/* border-collapse is a table property */

.wcard {
  float: left;
  /* margin:auto; */
  background-color: white;
  /*border-collapse: separate;*/
  padding: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #b2b2b2;
  /* Using margins and calc to determine offset */
  margin-top: calc(25vh - 40px);
  margin-left: calc(50vw - 70px);
}
.slidein {
  float: right;
  padding: 4px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img id="menu" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" width='50'>
  </header>

  <div class="wcard">wCard
  </div>
  <!-- Removed the outer div as it seems unnecessary -->
  <ul class="slidein">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li>Techniques</li>
    <li>About me</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the explicit answer but i already accepted another one! You got urself a upvote though :D

Comment: You are most welcome, sir. You got yourself an upvote as well, happy coding.:)